# Creating a plot from text file

Tags: c++, text, plot

So I would like to make a program like this: we choose .txt file to open and it makes a plot based on it. The format of data is:

```
12:52:11 30.2
12:53:52 31.2 
etc.
```

I think about doing it in C++, but first I want to check whether there's an easier option than Gnuplot (because I'm using Windows XP and can't use Linux terminal commands). I've seen DatPlot, but it's too inconvient for multiple files use. What do you recommend? I would be very grateful for any help. Cheers. :)

Comment: Fire up your nearest spreadsheet. E.g. in Excel use an xy plot. You might have to use an editor or maybe a script or C++ program to convert the text file.

Comment: I was thinking about Excel, but it is for my dad who isn't very into computer science but if it possible to do some script/macro that instantly parses information and automatically draws plot Excel would be also fine.
I mean, it should be as fast as possible and using Excel without any special macro would be laborious because there will be a few text files.

Comment: Haven't used this but I associate it with your requirements: http://www.gnuplot.info/